# How to get part of html content inserted in a Meteor template if the content is not in the page already

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor 0.7.0.1 with Spark and I have the following template that used to popover content, and the template is inserted at each post items.

```
<template name="postLinks">
    <a href="#" id="ui-popover-container-{{id}}" class="popover-list-trigger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </a>
    {{#if poppedUp}}
    <div id="link-popover-wrapper" style="display:none">
        <ul class="link-popover">
        {{#each linkOptions}}
            <li><a tabindex="-1" class="link-action" id="link-{{value}}" href="#">{{label}}</a>
            </li>
         {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

I want to print the div **"link-popover-wrapper"** only once the first time the template loaded. Subsequent template inserts in post items the div won't inserted so only one hidden div is in the page. I handled it using a template variable in following way.
var _poppeUp = true;

```
Template.postLiks.helpers({
    poppeUp : function () {
        if (_poppeUp) {
            _poppeUp = false;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

It is working for the first time the page is loaded and only one instance of the div **"link-popover-wrapper"** is in the page. The problem is when a post is updated and page is re-rendered the template variable still set to false and the div is not printed in the page. I wanted to reset that template variable when a page is re-rendered.

Is there a way to overcome this issue in Meteor ?

Comment: There is no "Meteor 0.7.0.1 with Blaze". Blaze was released in Meteor 0.8.

Comment: @AndrewMao Thanks and I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add code that does the opposite on page render:

```
Template.postLinks.rendered = function() {
  if (!_poppedUp)
    _poppedUp = true;
```

You didn't ask, but this strikes me as an odd way to implement this. Rather than `{{#if poppeUp}}`, why not `{{#with getFirstLinkPopoverWrapper}}` and then define a `getFirstLinkPopoverWrapper` helper that returns just the one `link-popover-wrapper` div that you want shown? Then you never need to worry about re-renders or tracking some variable.

> **EDIT**: Alternate implementation:

You could simply use jQuery to tell you whether or not an element of id `link-popover-wrapper` already exists on the page:

```
Template.postLinks.helpers({
  poppedUp: function() {
    return $("#link-popover-wrapper").length !== 0;
  }
}
```

That's it. If no such element exists, the length of the jQuery object is zero and the statement evaluates as `false` and `false` is returned. Otherwise `true` is returned and your template adds the element.

Comment: if I do the rendered update to the variable, page get an extra div of `link-popover-wrapper` every time when I update a post that does not contain the current `link-popover-wrapper` div. The `postLinks` template is included in each posts so I need only to get one `link-popover-wrapper` div per page. Can you elaborate your second option more?